# Javascript Recursive Call Producing Ghost Outcomes

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an function called changeCounter. It accepts a whole number and returns an array, changeDue, with the correct change in bills ordered from highest to lowest. Example:

```
    changeCounter(13)
    changeDue = [["TEN", 10], ["ONE", 1], ["ONE", 1], ["ONE", 1]]
```

The recursive function I created works as expected for numbers up to 5. Numbers greater than 5 returns extra bills. In other words it won't stop when `due = 0.` I've tried many variations. I would appreciate feedback as to what the problem is.

```
var changeDue = [];
var bills = [["ONE HUNDRED", 100],["TWENTY", 20],["TEN", 10],["FIVE", 5],["ONE", 1]];

function changeCounter(due) {
  for(var i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
    if(due >= bills[i][1] && due > 0) { // Should stop recursive loop here when due = 0!
      changeDue.push(bills[i]);
      console.log(due - bills[i][1]); // debug
      changeCounter(due - bills[i][1]);
    }
  }
  return changeDue;
}


console.log(changeCounter(8));
```

This outputs:

```
> [["FIVE", 5], ["ONE", 1], ["ONE", 1], ["ONE", 1], ["ONE", 1], ["ONE",
> 1], ["FIVE", 5]...]
```

Returns an array with 17 elements. Should only return first 4 elements.

Comment: What happens when you set a breakpoint in the debugger on this line and add a watch for both of these variables?   if(due >= bills[i][1] && due > 0)

Comment: Can you put some more test cases of what of what you expect to be the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `changeCounter()` recursively within itself, the value of `due` within the *calling* function doesn't change. So when `due` is 8, and you log a $5 bill, then call:

```
changeCounter(due - bills[i][1]);
```

to process the remaining $3, that's fine. But then that call returns to a world where `due == 8`, and your outer loop continues, throwing another $1 bill on the pile. Similar things happen in the `due == 3` version, and so on.

A `break;` will do the job, once you've made your recursive call:

```js
var changeDue = [];
var bills = [
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100],
  ["TWENTY", 20],
  ["TEN", 10],
  ["FIVE", 5],
  ["ONE", 1]
];

function changeCounter(due) {
  for (var i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
    if (due >= bills[i][1]) {
      changeDue.push(bills[i]);
      changeCounter(due - bills[i][1]);
      break;
    }
  }
  return changeDue;
}


console.log(changeCounter(8));
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That works great. Although I'm not sure why it works. I thought that once the recursive call is made, any code underneath would be ignored.

Comment: Nope. One function calls another function, and when the inner function returns, the outer function continues. The fact that a function is calling *itself* doesn't change that.

Comment: Ok. I understand what is going on now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the recursing inside the for loop, find a better place to put it in or just use a while loop.

```
function changeCounter(due) {
    var due = due,
        nextBill;
    while (due > 0) {
        nextBill = bills.reduce(function (acc, bill) {
            if (!acc && due >= bill[1]) acc = bill;
            return acc;
        }, false);
        due = due - nextBill[1];
        changeDue.push(nextBill);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a recursive function:

```
function changeCounter(amount) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0, billsCount = bills.length; i < billsCount; i++) {
        if (amount == 0) {
            break;
        }

        var numberOfBills = Math.floor(amount / bills[i][1]);
        if (numberOfBills > 0) {
            amount -= numberOfBills * bills[i][1];
            for (var j = 0; j < numberOfBills; j++) {
                result.push(bills[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```